# Custom shape button fails in Ext Panel Header

Tags: extjs

We have created a custom button but when added in ExtJs panel header the shape is not proper, but as a separate component it works fine, please find the two fiddles attached for the same.

[Custom Button on Panel header - Sencha Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1td7)

[Custom button as a separate component - Sencha Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1td2)

Answer (score 1):

if you add more height to the header tbar it works, the :before is chopped off.

[fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1tdv)